# How can I achieve Pulumi EKS RoleMappings with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, pulumi

There are Kubernetes RBAC in Amazon EKS with Pulumi instructions for TypeScript.

```js
const vpc = new awsx.ec2.Vpc("vpc", {});
const cluster = new eks.Cluster("eks-cluster", {
  vpcId             : vpc.id,
  subnetIds         : vpc.publicSubnetIds,
  instanceType      : "t2.medium",
  nodeRootVolumeSize: 200,
  desiredCapacity   : 1,
  maxSize           : 2,
  minSize           : 1,
  deployDashboard   : false,
  vpcCniOptions     : {
    warmIpTarget    : 4,
  },
  roleMappings      : [
    // Provides full administrator cluster access to the k8s cluster
    {
      groups    : ["system:masters"],
      roleArn   : clusterAdminRole.arn,
      username  : "pulumi:admin-usr",
    },
    // Map IAM role arn "AutomationRoleArn" to the k8s user with name "automation-usr", e.g. gitlab CI
    {
      groups    : ["pulumi:automation-grp"],
      roleArn   : AutomationRole.arn,
      username  : "pulumi:automation-usr",
    },
    // Map IAM role arn "EnvProdRoleArn" to the k8s user with name "prod-usr"
    {
      groups    : ["pulumi:prod-grp"],
      roleArn   : EnvProdRole.arn,
      username  : "pulumi:prod-usr",
    },
  ],
});
```

> Kubernetes RBAC in AWS EKS with open source Pulumi packages | Pulumi https://www.pulumi.com/blog/simplify-kubernetes-rbac-in-amazon-eks-with-open-source-pulumi-packages/

I'm looking for how to achieve this with .NET C#?
It looks like eks roleMappings extensions is only available for TypeScript, so that C# may be require to construct configmap manifest with Pulumi.Kubernetes?

> https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/blob/c672e225a765b11b07ea23e7b1b411483d7f38da/sdk/dotnet/Eks/Cluster.cs
>
> https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-eks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pulumi-eks` package is currently only available in TypeScript. There is a plan to bring it to all languages later this year, but for now you basically have two options:

1. Use TypeScript. If needed, break down your complete deployment into multiple stacks. The stack that defines the EKS package would be in TypeScript, while other stacks can be in C#.
2. Refer to the `pulumi-eks` implementation that you linked above and transfer that code manually to C#. This is a non-trivial work, so be careful with feasibility estimation.